# ADO.NET Entity : getting data from 3 tables

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

I have following table structure:

```
Table: Plant
 PlantID: Primary Key
 PlantName: String

Table: Party
 PartyID: Primary Key
 PartyName: String
 PlantID: link to Plant table

Table: Customer
 PartyID: Primary Key, link to Party
 CustomerCode: String
```

I'd like to have Customer entity object with following fields:

```
 PartyID: Primary Key
 CustomerCode: String
 PartyName: String
 PlantName: String
```

I am having trouble with PlantName field (which is brought from Plant table
I connected Customer to Party and Party to Plant with associations
However I can not connect Customer to Plant with association ( because it does not have one) 
I can not add Plant table to mapping, when I do that - I am getting following error:

```
Error 3024: Problem in Mapping Fragment starting at line 352: Must specify mapping for all key properties (CustomerSet.PartyID) of the EntitySet CustomerSet
```

Removing Plant association works.
Any hints or directions very appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this problem? I'm coming across the same thing.

Comment: Do you have foreign keys in your schema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get these fields by using the reference path on the Entity Object.

To get the PartyName, use this syntax:  `Customer.Party.PartyName`

To get the PlantName, use this syntax:  `Customer.Party.Plant.PlantName`

Comment: This works, but the field is not part of Customer object which is a drawback since I can not add it to datagrid (or any other databound controls) without writing a lot of code

Answer (score 2):

You can extend the Customer entity by using the public partial class:

```
public partial class Customer
{
  public string PartyName
  {
    get { return Party.PartyName; }
    set { Party.PartyName = value; }
  }

  public string PlantName
  {
    get { return Party.Plant.PlantName; }
    set { Party.Plant.PlantName = value; }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I came across this [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/010baca7-0d40-49a6-8fb3-466fb22471ac/) on MSDN that says you can create a read-only entity, which is enough of a downside to not use it alone, but it gets worse. You will also lose the ability to update *all* of the models dynamically based on the schema of the database.